# Replace ios app with completely new version

Tags: ios, xcode

I have app A on the app store

I built app B completely from scratch and would like to replace A with B

In order to test for conflicts I'd like to install App A on my iPhone (from the store) then attempt to install B from Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the below steps:

1)Install app A from app store on a device.

2)Create an archive of app B.

Make sure  the following points while creating app B you use.

- Build version of app B should be greater then that of app A.
- The same bundle identifier of app A should be used for App B.

3)Connect the device on which app A was downloaded.Using iTunes update app A with app B.

NOTE : If you have used core data in app A,you need to be careful about the migration process if you have updated something in app B.

Answer (score 1):

In xcode click the project file.

Click the app under 'Targets' on the left

Either search for 'bundle' or scroll down to 'Packaging'

There is a field called 'Project Bundle Identifier', double click and change to A (or whatever your app name is)